Adding a listener to all jobs and steps in Spring Batch
I'm working on a Spring Batch project and I'm trying to replace the codecentric dependency since I'm upgrading to a newer Java version. Due to the Java upgrade, the dependency is no longer properly functioning in my code. It was used for different use cases, such as registering a listener to all jobs and steps via the ListenerProvider interface. Previously, we have overwritten the methods jobExecutionListeners and stepExecutionListeners and returned our custom listener. Here is a small code snippet how it was used:
package my.package;

import de.codecentric.batch.configuration.ListenerProvider;    
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Configuration
public class CommonBatchConfiguration implements ListenerProvider {

    @Override
    public Set<JobExecutionListener> jobExecutionListeners() {
        Set<JobExecutionListener> listeners = new HashSet<>();
        listeners.add(new MyCustomListener());
        return listeners;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<StepExecutionListener> stepExecutionListeners() {
        Set<StepExecutionListener> listeners = new HashSet<>();
        listeners.add(new MyCustomListener());
        return listeners;
    }
}

Since we are creating jobs and steps via the JobBuilder/StepBuilder and read them from XMLs and JavaConfigs, I'm not sure how to inject this listener to all jobs and steps. I tried to build a CommonBuilder helper class that creates predefined JobBuilder/StepBuilder classes. These are used in all job and step creations but this did not work for the use case when reading from XMLs and JavaConfig.
The XML and JavaConfig Jobs are added via AutomaticJobRegistrar.addApplicationContextFactory. An example for the XMLs looks like this:
for (Resource resource: xmlConfigurations) {
    automaticJobRegistrar.addApplicationContextFactory(new GenericApplicationContextFactory(resource));
}

Does anybody have an idea to solve this? If you need more input, I'm happy to provide you more
